# Can I use a font under Apache Licence 2.0 in a commercially distributed game?

Tags: apache, fonts, licensing

Can I use a font under Apache Licence 2.0 in a commercially distributed game? The font will be included as texture in a modified form (with some decorations).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, you can.

But you MUST keep any copyright notices, state changes in the original font (if any) and include the original text of the licence in your game.

The guidelines for applying the licence are found in the [Apache website](https://www.apache.org/dev/apply-license.html).

*Sources:*

- [Apache Licence – Full text](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
- [TL;DR Legal](https://www.tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2-0-apache-2-0)
- [Applying the Apache license to new software](https://www.apache.org/dev/apply-license.html)

Comment: For a super quick info about other licences, check http://choosealicense.com/

Comment: If I'm using an Apache licensed font throughout a book, what should I do? Should I include the license file as pages or I don't need to?

Comment: @mozcelikors It depends on what you are calling a "book". If it is a printed book, you don't have to include the original license text or any copyright notice, as you are not distributing the font files. But if your book is an e-book, you may have to include the license and copyright notices, depending on the file format used to distribute it. If is a PDF, you may actually have to include the license, as there are different ways to incorporate a font in a PDF. If it's an EPUB, you should definitely include the license and copyright notices, as you will need to embed the font files.

Comment: @mozcelikors You see, this is all about distribution of source files.

Comment: Thank you very much.